# Is there a way to change attributes of a form based on one attribute?

Tags: django

I'm using a ClassBasedView, where field x is a char field with specific choices.

I want to know if it's possible to hide field y and z before choosing x and to add field y or z based on choice.

```
class BookCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):


    model = Book

    fields = ['x', 'y', 'z']
```

Comment: You can do this with javascript on the page.

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this by using JavaScript (including jQuery) to dynamically show/hide and add/remove fields based on the selected choice in the 'x' field. Below is an example using jQuery to hide 'y' and 'z' initially and show them when a specific choice in 'x' is selected.

Here's an example script to get you started. Please adjust it according to your specific needs:

```
<!-- Include jQuery library -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js"></script>

<!-- Your form HTML -->
<form id="book-form" method="post" action="{% url 'your_create_view_url' %}">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_p }}
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<!-- Your jQuery script -->
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    // Hide fields 'y' and 'z' initially
    $('#id_y, #id_z').hide();

    // Attach change event to 'x' field
    $('#id_x').on('change', function () {
      var selectedValue = $(this).val();

      // Hide 'y' and 'z' fields
      $('#id_y, #id_z').hide();

      // Show 'y' or 'z' based on the selected value in 'x'
      if (selectedValue === 'your_specific_choice_for_y') {
        $('#id_y').show();
      } else if (selectedValue === 'your_specific_choice_for_z') {
        $('#id_z').show();
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```